# Disabling the iPhoto Photo Stream App badge icon without disabling shared streams?

Tags: photos.app, dock, photo-stream

When I have new photos available in my shared photo streams, the iPhoto icon in the dock has a red circle with a number in it, also known as a "Badge App Icon".

I went to System Preferences -> Notifications -> Photo Stream and disabled everything, but the badge app icon on iPhoto still shows.

For now I have disabled shared photo streams completely from iPhoto -> Preferences, and that has removed the badge app icon, but I would prefer to still keep it enabled.

How can I disable this badge app icon?

Answer (score 1):

I got rid of the red circle number (the notification), by going to 
system preferences ➔ iCloud ➞ and then unchecking the box to the left of "Photos"   When you re-check the checkbox, the notifications will briefly display in the upper right part of the screen, telling you about photo stream invitations you have received from other people.

Comment: This worked for me too.  I had an album that insisted it was new until I did this.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the badge on the Photos app icon in Notification Center settings. Go to **System Preferences** → **Notifications** → **iPhoto** → **Badge App Icon** and uncheck the box.

[image: System Preferences → Notifications → iPhoto]

<sup>I don't have iPhoto on my system, so replace *iCloud Photos* with *iPhoto*.</sup>

Comment: As mentioned in my question, I tried this and it didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: Well, to be more specific, I tried it by disabling everything from "Photo Stream" in the preference pane. iPhoto doesn't even appear in the list.

Comment: @CoryKlein Yes, disabling the Badge App Icon for Photo Stream shouldn't do anything since Photo Stream isn't the app showing the badge… iPhoto *should* appear in the list though, as it is an app capable of showing notifications…

Comment: I heartily agree. I don't understand why iPhoto isn't in the Notifications preference pane either. Doesn't make any sense. Oh, Jobs, why did you have to leave us?